# How to draw border around NSTextView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I'm simply trying to draw a one point black border around an NSTextView and am running into trouble. The code below is a subclass of NSTextView:

```
override init(frame: NSRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?)
{
    super.init(frame:frame, textContainer: textContainer)

    self.wantsLayer = true
    self.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer?.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.layer?.cornerRadius = 0.0
}
```

The `self.wantsLayer = true` code causes the `NSTextView` to disappear. Is there another way to accomplish this?

EDIT: This is how I'm adding the `NSTextView` aka `PageView` to its parent `view`:

```
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer()
    textContainer.widthTracksTextView = true
    textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true

    let pageView = PageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: pagesViewOriginY, width: self.paperSize.width, height: self.paperSize.height), textContainer: textContainer)
    self.addSubview(pageView);

    self.layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer);
```

Comment: Disappears? Was it showing the first time it loads? Show how you are adding this text view to your view.

Comment: @Frankenstein Yes it shows when I remove self.wantsLayer = true. I added the code you requested above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative is to create a separate class for the text view and use draw() to provide the frame:

```
class TextView: NSTextView {
override func draw(_ rect: NSRect) {
  super.draw(rect)
  let border:NSBezierPath = NSBezierPath(rect: bounds)
  let borderColor = NSColor.black
  borderColor.set()
  border.lineWidth = 2.0
  border.stroke()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to use a scrollview and set the border like this:

```
scrollView.borderType = .lineBorder
```

Alternatively, you could embed the text view into an NSView and draw a border around it:

```
let embedderRect = NSMakeRect(10, 590, _wndW - 20, 252)
let embedderView = NSView(frame:embedderRect)
let textStorage = NSTextStorage()
let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
let textContainer = NSTextContainer()
layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
let textView = NSTextView(frame:NSMakeRect( 1, 1, embedderRect.size.width - 2, embedderRect.size.height - 2 ), textContainer: textContainer)
embedderView.wantsLayer = true
embedderView.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
embedderView.layer?.borderWidth = 1.0
embedderView.layer?.cornerRadius = 0.0
embedderView.addSubview (textView)
window.contentView!.addSubview (embedderView)
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've thought about using a parent view to do the border but want to try and avoid it. I might have to do it that way though in the end. Don't get why NSTextView won't allow me to do it.